# How to code jQuery templates in Haml (phphaml)?

Tags: php, jquery, haml, jquery-templates

Trying to combine jQuery templates with phphaml...

```
%script#foo{:type=>"x-jquery-tmpl"}
  ${bar}
```

... yelds a notice and invalid compiled code:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in (PATH)/app/vendor/phphaml/HamlParser.class.php on line 474

<script type="x-jquery-tmpl" id="foo">
  $
</script>
```

Phphaml seems to take issue with the $ and {} symbols. Any way of getting around this? I've been searching for a while, with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the curly braces? Maybe using `{{` and `}}`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't quite work. Escaping was a good idea, though, and led me to try having php echo the troublesome expressions, like so: `= '${foo}'`. While it manages to get some expressions past phphaml's parser, it way too unwieldy a way to write code. Guess php + haml + jquery templates is just a no go. Thanks anyway, again.